# moved site to https now search console won't index pages in new https search console property

Tags: ssl, https, google-search-console

After installing an SSL certificate on our server I created 2 new properties in Google Search Console and specified the non-www as the default address. However, after 7 days none of the pages are being indexed. They are still being indexed in the http properties though. Any ideas how to get the new https site indexed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a new Property for https. You can't move the old one with http://.
Tip: Make a backup of your old search data, to see the changes after switch to https://
Tip2: Don't forget to change the https setting in Analytics (here you don't need a new property), but you must reconnect the search console with the new property.